# Для реализации задачи не существует контейнера для View?

Tags: android

На самом деле разметка сложная, пишу только главное. Проблема заключается в отсутсвии `Layout`-а.

Допустим, у меня есть некий контейнер с зеленым фоном, внутри которого внизу расположена кнопка. Под этим контейнером расположен еще один с красным фоном.

Задача - анимировать по нажатию на кнопку красную панель (изначально ее нет). Тоесть, по первому клику снизу выдвигается красная панель. При последующих кликах она задвигается/выдвигается. Что-то типа `SnackBar`, но... верхний контейнер **должен зависеть** от красного при анимации - подниматься и опускаться вместе с ним!

Как это можно сделать? Ни один из `Layout`-ов так не умеет.

P.S Нашел инфу как поднимать/опускать `FAB` при выдвигании/задвигании `SnackBar`, но у меня обычные `Layout`-ы, к тому же поднимать/опускать нужно не `View` а целый контейнер.

Comment: В очередной раз повторю вам, изучить подробнее `CoordinatorLayout` и `Behavior`. Это не простой механизм поэтому готовое решение вам мало кто сможет предложить

Comment: Что мешает просто положить зеленую и красную панель в `LinearLayout` и анимировать их вместе?

Comment: @Amis Shaykh, как? Анимирую нижнюю скрывая/показывая полностью, а верхнюю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать примерно так:

```
void animateTop(){
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 200);
animator.setDuration(250);
animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float val = (float)animation.getAnimatedValue();
        view1.setTranslationX(-1 * val);
        view2.setTranslationX(form.getHeight() - val);
    }
});
animator.start();}
```

где: form - основной контейнер, view1 - зеленый контейнер, view2 - красный контейнер.

Для обратной анимации просто меняем местами цифры 0,200 на 200,0 (выставьте свои значения).

ps: Код написан в текстовом редакторе, так что могут быть некоторые ошибки в написании, однако сам принцип правилен.

Comment: Ого, огромное спасибо за верное направление! Я поменял `setTranslationX` методы на `setTranslationY` и изменил `duration` на 2500 чтобы успеть заметить как происходит анимация. Также поменял местами 200 и 0. Нижняя панель исчезает мгновенно а верхняя начинает двигаться с высоты на 200px больше чем она была на то место по умолчанию. Также я не пойму как сделать чтоба изначально она была скрыта

Comment: Получилось! Пришлось только выставить в xml `translationY` 200px обоим `view`. В реальный проект перенесу придется ставить их в коде. Единственный минус - верхняя панель сместилась вниз, как исправить? Может прикрутить паддинг?

Comment: Надо как-то сделать чтобы ничего не надо было указывать в `xml`. Ток если в нем указать заранее `gone` на нижнюю панель. Вот только потом как анимировать выдвигание? Если его перед началом обьявлять то выдвигание будет дерганым

Comment: Xyx, вообщем я запутался :(

Comment: Стоп. Этот способ мне вообще не подходит. Я забылся, что у меня список и не надо ничего транслэйтить. Нужно чтобы панель выдвигалась как бы поверх него. Мне кажется что это не решаемо

Comment: Я кажется вообще не то написал в вопросе (

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вашу разметку. Тогда будет проще. Возможно в вашем случае может быть и более удобное решение.